# Property access conversion to an activity is not supported for property 'Today' defined on type 'System.DateTime'

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I am developing a Sharepoint 2013 add-in. Writing the workflow, when using DateTime.today, I get this error: Property access conversion to an activity is not supported for property 'Today' defined on type 'System.DateTime'.

I read online several errors like this one, where people suggest to modify the trusted surface. I did it, but I keep getting the same error.

This is the code I write in the AllowedTypes.xml file:

```
<AllowedTypes>
  <Assembly Name="mscorlib,  Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <Namespace Name="System">
    <Type>TimeSpan</Type>
    <Type>DateTime</Type>
  </Namespace>
  </Assembly>

  <Assembly Name="mscorlib,  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <Namespace Name="System">
    <Type>TimeSpan</Type>
    <Type>DateTime</Type>
  </Namespace>
  </Assembly>
</AllowedTypes>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. I'll develop the project on Office 365.

How can I solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using DateTime.UtcNow ?

Answer (score 2):

As per user21251's comment, by using `System.DateTime.UtcNow`the solution builds.